# Using MVC 4.0 and JQueryUI DatePicker, I Need to "Refresh" the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-4, onselect

I'm stuck on this. This is my first MVC 4.0 project. My Index page on my controller displays some information based on a date, it defaults to today.

I'm using the JQueryUI datepicker at the top of the page to let the user pick a different date. I basically need to "Refresh" the page when the user picks a new date.

I would post my code but I've tried at least a dozen different things, none of which have worked. Incidentally, setting the default date doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try **onSelect** callback in datepicker

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: callback ....
```

and inside this call back use page refresh.

please refer the document: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the page in datepicker's onSelect callback, to reload the page take a look at this http://jqfaq.com/how-to-reload-a-page-with-a-different-argument/ in this post you can see how they are loadng the page with some args.